# Contention for semaphore by two processes executing down_interruptible call simultaeously

Tags: linux-kernel, semaphore

Is it possible that a semaphore with an initial value of 1 be acquired simultaneously by two processes which are running on different processor cores via the down_interruptible call.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible for 1-initialized semaphore to be acquired simultaneously by different processes.

Semaphores, like other synchronisation mechanisms, are intended to use by different processes/threads. Why do you think that accesses from different processors can break them?

Comment: Thanks I understand the basic philosophy behind semaphores, but I am unable to understand how semaphores have been implemented to achieve their purpose in SMP systems. I suppose some special machine instructions are needed to achieve the purpose.

Comment: `I suppose some special machine instructions are needed to achieve the purpose.` - Yes, there are special instructions, which are excuted *atomically* wrt to all others CPU and cores. Such instructions are named `atomic instructions` or `locked instructions`.

Comment: Tsyvarev can you be more specific with an example of linux on x86

Comment: On x86 atomic instructions use LOCK prefix. See, e.g. `atomic_*` functions in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/atomic.h. Implementation of semaphores uses some of these functions.

Comment: Thnx Tsyvarev this was very helpful